# Oracle Sum Based On Condition

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

SQL first so I can reference it lower:

```
SELECT ID, 
       SUM(length(substr(DATA_STRING, instr(DATA_STRING,'P')+1))) 
FROM DATA P, PLC PP 
WHERE P.ID = PP.ID 
  AND instr(DATA_STRING, 'F') = 0 
GROUP BY ID
```

The function above looks for the P in each data string and counts up how many characters are in the string.

So my problem is thus, I have two conditions that can occur, one where the data string could contain the P as in above, or when it contains a F. I need to be able to check for both and then sum up the total. The issue with the above is that I sum in a 0 if that condition when the string has an F occurs.

I almost need the equivalent of SUMIF in Excel so that I could say if when I search for P it's 0, then look for the F and add in that length and vice versa.

Please let me know if you have suggestions!

Comment: Isn't this what GROUP BY/HAVING is for?

Comment: @duffymo I think its more complex than that. I could use HAVING to capture both conditoins, but the `instr` portion that is used in the calculation for the length would also need to change

Comment: Have you tried a case statement here? sum(case when condition = true then value_to_sum else 0 end)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`length(substr(DATA_STRING, instr(DATA_STRING,'P')+1))`?  This is doing a lot of work.

From what I can tell, you want sum of the number of characters after a `'P'` or `'F'` in the string.  If so:

```
SELECT ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN data_string like '%P%'
                THEN len(DATA_STRING) - (instr(DATA_STRING, 'P') + 1) ELSE 0
           END) as Num_P,
       SUM(CASE WHEN data_string like '%F%'
                THEN len(DATA_STRING) - (instr(DATA_STRING, 'F') + 1) ELSE 0
           END) as Num_F
FROM DATA P JOIN
     PLC PP 
     ON P.ID = PP.ID 
GROUP BY ID;
```

I also fixed the join syntax to use explicit joins.